# Can I get a value of a let inside an object created with a function?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to understand better the mechanics of values inside objects created with funcitons.

```
let createCounter = function(init) {
    let ans = init
    return {
        increment(){return ++ans},
        decrement(){return --ans},
        reset(){return ans = init},
        ans,
    }
};
myob1=createCounter(3)
myob2=createCounter(10)
console.log(myob1.increment()) // 4
console.log(myob2.increment()) // 11
console.log(myob1.ans) // 3
console.log(myob2.ans) // 10
```

Does the value of 'ans' property stay constant after creating an object?
Can i directly get it's current value within this syntax?

As I understood the value of the let is bond with each object after creating and when I try to get it's value using object property, it simply appeals to the 'ans=init' and displays starting value?
BTW i'm in the very beggining of my JS studying, please don't be angry on me :з

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you return `{ans}`, that's equivalent to writing `{ans: ans}`, where the second `ans` references the current value of ans.

This means that when you later assign a different value to `ans`, the object `{ans}` still references the initial value.

To resolve this, use a getter. Change `{ans}` to `{get ans() {return ans}}` like this:

```js
let createCounter = function(init) {
    let ans = init
    return {
        increment(){return ++ans},
        decrement(){return --ans},
        reset(){return ans = init},
        get ans() {return ans},
    }
};
myob1=createCounter(3)
myob2=createCounter(10)
console.log(myob1.increment()) // 4
console.log(myob2.increment()) // 11
console.log(myob1.ans) // 4
console.log(myob2.ans) // 11
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are returning actually is this :

```
{
        increment(){return ++ans},
        decrement(){return --ans},
        reset(){return ans = init},
        ans: 3 // if init was 3,
}
```

So when you update the value of `ans`, you don't update the value that was passed in the object (because the function has already computed its return value) but only the variable `ans` present in the function

To access the attribute `ans` of the object, you should use `this` (just like if you are in a class)

```
let createCounter = function(init) {
    let ans = init
    return {
        increment(){return ++this.ans},
        decrement(){return --this.ans},
        reset(){return this.ans = init},
        ans,
    }
};
```

[Andrew Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5898421/andrew-parks) solution works as well. Both approachs can be used

Comment: Note that if you added in another getter like this: `get otherAns(){return ans}`, it would return the original value, even though you appeared to increment it. This is because after calling `increment`, there are two different `ans` variables - one set as a property of the `createCounter` function, and one as a variable declared inside the scope of the `createCounter` function. This is a confusing situation to be in.

Comment: You're right ! But i think the approach used depends on the philosophy we have, do we want to only use the properties of the returned object or everything in the scope of the function ? In a very OOP way of doing things, i prefer my approach. If I wanted to add a getter, i would've make it return `this.ans`, because i don't want to access the `ans` variable of the function. But this is my opinion, i understand yours

Comment: Btw I meant to type above "one set as a property of the object returned by the `createCounter` function". And yes, I think we would probably agree that the best solution of all would be to have just created a proper class here